Determine which symmetric keys are encoded by a certificate in SQL Server
I have a few keys and certificates in my database, found using
select * from sys.symmetric_keys
select * from sys.certificates

Is it possible to determine which certificates encrypt which symmetric key?

You can find related certificates using the thumbprint field via the key_encryptions  table
select sk.symmetric_key_id, c.certificate_id
from sys.symmetric_keys sk
join sys.key_encryptions ke  on sk.symmetric_key_id= ke.key_id
join sys.certificates c    on    ke.thumbprint=c.thumbprint

